# Removing $1/f$ noise with lock-in-amplifiers

Tags: experimental-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering, signal-processing, noise

On the Wikipedia page for [1/f noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_noise) (at the bottom of the page) it suggests the noise can be reduced if the signal of interest is at DC. DC signals suffer from significant 1/f noise, so one method of removing this is to modulate the signal at some higher frequency and use a [lock-in-amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-in_amplifier) to detect the now modulated signal synchronously. However, to my understanding, lock-in-amplifiers then convert the modulated signal back into a DC signal, surely again limited by the 1/f noise as before, so how is this method helpful for DC signals?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Of course it's also an appropriate question for Electrical engineering. However, Lock-in-detection is ubiquitous in experimental physics, it is so widely used but unfortunately not explained in proportion to its use. It would be good to hear from physicists as well.

Comment: The idea is to modulate the signal, that would otherwise be at DC, i.e., 0 Hz, *before* it gets contaminated with the 1/f noise. So the modulated signal is up above the 1/f noise corner. Then demodulation shifts the signal back to DC and the 1/f noise on the modulated signal gets shifted as well, so it is not near DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the original signal is $y$ with noise spectrum $s(f)$. Let $A$ be the gain of an amplifier, and let $z(f)$ be the noise introduced by the amplifier at the output.
A d.c. amplifier of gain $A_{dc}$ would produce at its output approximately
$$
A_{dc} (y + s(0)) + z(0).
$$
There is more than one way to modulate the signal so as to use a lock-in amplifier. One way is to chop the signal, so that it appears and disappears altogether at the chosen frequency and phase. In this case the output is approximately
$$
A\left( y + s(f)\right) + z(0).
$$
Another method is to modulate some parameter $x$, in which case the output is something like
$$
A\left( \frac{dy}{dx} + s(f)\right) + z(0).
$$
Broadly speaking, the d.c. amplifier amplifies the d.c. noise whereas the lock-on amplifier amplifies the noise at the chosen frequency $f$. So if the latter is smaller (which it almost always is if you pick $f$ sensibly) then the lock-in method is superior.
In practice you would only use the amplifier when $z(0)$ does not dominate $A s(f)$.

(Thanks to Jamie1989 for pointing out an omission in the first version of this answer.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the lock-in amplifier isn't the output proportional to the derivative of the signal y, why would that not be the case for how you have described it?

Comment: @jamie1989 Good point! I have modified my answer accordingly.